# Finding an element with class name in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(filename), "lxml")
dd = {}

rows = soup.find_all('tr')

for r in rows:
    td = r.find_all('td')
    print(td)
```

Using the code above, printing the `td` would give me the following:

```
    [<td class="num cell-icon-string" data-sort-value="1"><i class="pki pkiAll n1" data-sprite="pkiAll n1"></i> 001</td>, <td class="cell-icon-string"><a class="ent-name" href="/pokedex/bulbasaur" title="View pokedex for #001 Bulbasaur">Bulbasaur</a></td>, <td class="cell-icon"><a class="type-icon type-grass" href="/type/grass">Grass</a><br/><a class="type-icon type-poison" href="/type/poison">Poison</a></td>, <td class="num-total">318</td>, <td class="num">45</td>, <td class="num">49</td>, <td class="num">49</td>, <td class="num">65</td>, <td class="num">65</td>, <td class="num">45</td>]
    [<td class="num cell-icon-string" data-sort-value="2"><i class="pki pkiAll n2" data-sprite="pkiAll n2"></i> 002</td>, <td class="cell-icon-string"><a class="ent-name" href="/pokedex/ivysaur" title="View pokedex for #002 Ivysaur">Ivysaur</a></td>, <td class="cell-icon"><a class="type-icon type-grass" href="/type/grass">Grass</a><br/><a class="type-icon type-poison" href="/type/poison">Poison</a></td>, <td class="num-total">405</td>, <td class="num">60</td>, <td class="num">62</td>, <td class="num">63</td>, <td class="num">80</td>, <td class="num">80</td>, <td class="num">60</td>]
```

From this `td`, I would specifically like to get the type name and the name:

```
<a class="type-icon type-grass" href="/type/grass">Grass</a><br/>
```

and

```
<a class="ent-name" href="/pokedex/bulbasaur" title="View pokedex for #001 Bulbasaur">Bulbasaur</a></td>
```

But I am having a hard time accessing those specific elements.

How can I do this with beautifulsoup?

Comment: Try `td.get(something)`. Usually BS elements are accessible like a dictionary.

Comment: read all pages in [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and you will not have to ask.